# Instantiating two instances of a class

Tags: java

I have a quick question

Suppose I were to create a data definition class named Campaign

and then I want to make an implementation class

Let's say in this implementation class I have a few variables(campaignName, campaignType, campaignGoal) and some methods (getCampName, getCampType, getCampGoal).

I want to create two different campaigns classes, and then compare their information at the end of the program with a print method.

Would this be a proper way of declaring information for the first campaign:

```
Campaign campaign1 = new Campaign();
```

which is in the main method, and then let's say I want to get the name of the first campaign, which is just hardcoded for now

```
public static String campaign1.getCampName(){
  campaign1.setCampName("IT Student Scholarship Fund");
}
```

I just wanted to know how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't make the slightest sense.

Comment: I used to think that a `getter` was so trivial, it wasn't possible to get it wrong, but I stand corrected.  I suggest you use your IDE to generate the getters.  A getter just gets the value i.e. returns it. It doesn't do anything else and it's not `static`.

Answer (score 2):

getCampName() should look something like:

```
public String getCampName() { return this.campaignName; }
```

a then simply

```
campaign1.getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should stop the practice of putting all of your code in a main method. Instead, instantiate your Campaign instances and call methods on each one using a driver method in your primary class. In addition, you can override the equals() method to do the comparison (or implement Comparator).

```
public class CampaignTest{
    public void runTest(){
        Campaign c1 = new Campaign("First Campaign");
        Campaign c2 = new Campaign("Second Campaign");
        Campaign c11 = new Campaign("First Campaign");

        System.out.println("c1==c2: " + c1.equals(c2));
        System.out.println("c2==c11: " + c2.equals(c11));
        System.out.println("c1==c11: " + c1.equals(c11));
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        CampaignTest test = new CampaignTest();
        test.runTest();
    }

    private class Campaign{
        private String name;

        public Campaign(String n){
            this.name = n;
        }

        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object other){
            if(other instanceof Campaign && ((Campaign)other).getName().equals(name)){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```